# How to integrate Bar Code Scanner with Unity3D? Is there any free or paid plugin for this?

Tags: unity-game-engine, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am trying to make a database(SQlite) application in Unity3D. I know its very bad practice to make an application in Unity3D, but i just want to try it in Unity3D.
I want to integrate Bar Code Scanner in the application. My expectation form this scanner is to get data from bar code and display on Input Field and also Generate Bar code after inserting data into database.

So, Is there any free or paid plugin for this?
If Yes then help me with some reference links. If No, Help me with some ideas to get started. I am using Unity3D version 5.2

Here is the Picture of my Bar Code Scanner.

[image]

Help me Please, Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try Zxing, it has unity integration

https://zxingnet.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will take a look and get back to you.